# Access is Denied Exception when calling JavaScript function from Java in IE

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, liveconnect

I am getting Access Denied exception when I am calling a Java Script Function from Java Applet only in IE. ( modified my original question with updated information.)

Here is my HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function uploadComplete() {
       alert("in Upload Complete");
       ju.doneUpload(true);
   }
</script>
```

`ju` is declared globally in the same page which calls the doneUpload from a different JavaScript file. I have included MAYSCRIPT in my applet Tag.

Java Code [After adding AccessController] :

```
 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
 public Object run() {

JSObject scriptObject = getScriptObject(uploadDialogBox.applet);
if(scriptObject != null) {
    try {
        // this is the call where it   throws an exception
       **scriptObject.call("uploadComplete", null);**
    } catch(JSException e) {
        System.out.println("exception " + e.getMessage() 
            + " WrappendException " + e.getWrappedException()
            + " stack trace " + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
return null;
}
```

});

```
private JSObject getScriptObject(JApplet appletInstance) {
    JSObject result = null;
    // JSObject doc = null;
    try {
        result = JSObject.getWindow(appletInstance);
        // doc = (JSObject) result.getMember("document");
    } catch (JSException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in getScriptObject : " + e.getMessage()
            + " Wrappend exception " + e.getWrappedException());
    }
    return result;
}
```

It throws an `JSException: Access is denied`

The `alert` function in `uploadComplete` is not called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: its difficult to read what is code here and what is your text... can you please use StackOverFlow.com syntax when representing code? (placing 4 spaces in front of each line of code puts it into a codebox)

Comment: I've formatted the code to generate better response.

Comment: well... he may not be getting "better" responses... but at least its properly formatted now.

Comment: What OS/Java version are you using?

Comment: Using Windows XP and JRE version 1.6.0_05

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5335198) help?

A summary from that answer on the Sun forums:

Hello, I had same problem. I solved it, you just need to implement applets method like this:

```
public void f() {
   AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
      public Object run() {
         // do something
         return null;
      }
   });
}
```

The only problem with this approach is that when you call method for the first time, it takes pretty long time to respond (4-5s), and every next time, response is immediately.

**Edit**: OK, a second potential solution is to use getDocument() as described in [this article](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html). One word of warning, in our testing, we have seen that this is not always reliable on Firefox on the Mac. The essence of this method is to do:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:uploadComplete()"));
```

Comment: It still doesn't help ... I wrapped AccessController over my code and still get Access is Denied exception. Should I check applet.policy or crossdomain.xml ?

Comment: I had showDocumnet before 

URL url = new URL("javascript:uploadComplete()"); uploadDialogBox.applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "_self"); 

but it doesn't work in IE but works in FF. So was trying liveconnect as an alternative.

Comment: Actually, after wrapping my code over AccessController it works in FF but doesn't for IE. So comes down to a browser issue ? It gives the "Access is Denied." when scriptObject.call("uploadComplete", null);
 is called.

Comment: My guess is that this is a browser issue, and that your IE is probably locked down and won't allow external access to the DOM.